# Which Angular CLI version to install for Angular 4 and upto which version of angular I can use for Node 6.x and NPM 3.x?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am planning to build an App using Angular, but my node version is 6.14.X and npm 3.X. I figured from Angular 4 documentation that I can build Apps using Angular 4 on the current node and npm versions I have and I cannot update my node and npm as my device doesn’t support. How to find the which Angular CLI version to install for Angular 4?

Comment: angular-cli version 1.x should work.

Comment: Can you also suggest which is the latest Angular version I can use for above node and npm versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular 5 or lower version requires Node 6.9.x and npm 3.x.x but Angular 6 requires Node 8.x and npm 5.x

Check here for supported node and npm versions:
[Angular 5](https://v5.angular.io/guide/quickstart#devenv)
[Angular 6](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart#devenv)

Comment: If that was actually a quote, please also provide a link to the source. Also: no, this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: [Edit] the question, it's always useful to provide references, but note that you're not actually *quoting* that page, which only contains the latter fact.